# How to process twig array?

Tags: php, twig

Im configuring a twig template. How do I process this array:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"Balkon";i:1;s:9:"Møbleret";i:2;s:4:"Pool";}
```

with twig code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a a serialized array. Call [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it.

Comment: Extend twig with a Twig_Filter/Twig_Function that calls the unserialize function. `$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('unserialize', 'unserialize'); $twig->addFilter($filter);` and then do `{% for value in (array|unserialize) %}`

Comment: can you not 'unserialize' it before you pass the variable to twig?

Comment: Thansks for the help. You helped me get to the bottom of the problem!

Comment: This answer is absolutely WRONG! The question clearly states that it is related to Twig.